# Ошибка NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object при обновлении Text объекта

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

Делаю простую игру. Когда игрок собирает ящики, то обновляется объект Text, который показывает кол-во собраных ящиков. Но получаю ошибку:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object

и текст не обновляется. Как исправить?

Класс CounterController

```
 public class CounterController : MonoBehaviour {
   int numberOfBoxes;
   Text counterView;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {
     ResetCounter ();
   }

   public void IncrementCounter(){
     numberOfBoxes++;
     counterView.text = numberOfBoxes.ToString();
   }

   public void ResetCounter(){
     numberOfBoxes=0;
     counterView.text = numberOfBoxes.ToString();
   }
}
```

Клас PickUpBox

```
public class PickUpBox : MonoBehaviour {
  CounterController counterController;

  void Start () {
    counterController = GameObject.Find ("Manager").GetComponent<CounterController> ();
    if (counterController == null) {
      Debug.LogError ("CounterController не найден.");
    }
  }

  void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D other) {
    if (other.gameObject.name == "Girl") {
      Destroy (this.gameObject);
      counterController.IncrementCounter ();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: У вас counterView в ResetCounter нужно сделать new Text перед тем, как обращаться к counterView.text

Answer (score -1):

По коду не видно, где переменной counterView задается ссылка на компонент, который и должен отображать текст.
Самым простым вариантом для Вас будет сделать переменную либо общедоступной

```
public Text counterView;
```

либо видимой для Инспектора

```
[SerializeField]
Text counterView;
```

и после этого в Инспекторе задать значение переменной, перетащив нужный компонент Text.